# How to import a custom UMD module in a Webpack 4 project

Tags: javascript, webpack, umd

I am developping a library that needs to work in both node and a react app. I use a webpack 4 project that generates a UMD module, but I have a problem when I try to import it in a simple webpack project.

When I use `import lib from 'myLib';` lib is undefined

This is what my lib look like

```
export const printMsg = function() {
  return "This is a message from the lib";
};
```

With this webpack configuration

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "mylib.js",
    library: "mylib",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    globalObject: `(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this)`
  }
};
```

for now I'm using a boilerplate project (https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter) to test.

I used `npm install --save mylib` to add it, and my dist code is inside my `node_modules` folder.
My index.js file look like this :

```
import "../styles/index.scss";
import lib from "watson-tile-lib";
console.log(lib);
```

When I run the page I got `undefined` in my browser console.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

what is your main field in package.json? It should be the builded target like:

```
main: "dist/mylib.js"
```